# Spring Boot @ConditionalOnProperty for yaml array

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have an application.yaml file with N number of items in the array under the key of configs.

```
uk.co.iamsimonsmale.dynamic-strings:
  lastName: Smale
  configs:
    - beanName: simonBean
      firstName: Simon
    - beanName: griffinBean
      firstName: Griffin
```

I am trying to find a way to use that key in as a `@ConditionalOnProperty` preferably without something custom as I want to share this as a part of a starter.

```
   @ConditionalOnProperty("uk.co.iamsimonsmale.dynamic-strings.configs")
```